# iOS XCode Apple LLVM 5.1 Error Too Many Errors Semantic Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

First of all, my project builds fine initially.

Then I integrate VideoStream SDK for iOS into a standalone app, and it works.
Then I integrate VideoStream SDK into my actual project, and set up search paths for header files for the library, but then my project gets these issues:

[image: errorimage]

Comment: 1. The class file `MDSprewadView.m` has warnings.Hint: Fix all warnings. 2. Are the errors associated with a file and a line in the file? 3. Are there link errors, if so what are they.

Comment: MDSpreadView has a value conversion issue for returning nil for a function that is supposed to return BOOL. Not a big deal. Other warnings are deprecations and value conversion issues and unused functions. There are no errors associated with a line in a file, otherwise I think this would be much simpler to solve. Those are all the errors in my project. When I remove the library and the code that references it, but keep the header search paths, the project builds. But when I try to use it, it does not. The library works pretty much standalone in a test app.

Comment: The issue is with the LLVM Compiler and using C++ somehow. After a lot of googling, I thought it had to do with specifying recursion in the header search paths. Some people solved similar issues by making the search paths non recursive. I did that, and I still have the issue

Comment: Sorry, but there's only one reason for warnings: lazy programmers.

Comment: Or people that recognize that there are too many problems in the world to solve to be bothered by value conversion issues from imported libraries that do not affect the code.

Comment: Many, many people report similar issues due to having recursion in their search paths, but I have removed all recursive search paths. Still have the issue.

Comment: Why not fix the issues and send them a patch? These appear to all be issues with the correct use of the language, and should be considered extreme code smell - the quality of the 3rd party code you are trying to use appears to be *very* poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen this solution posted ANYWHERE after so much time googling since the time I posted, but I disabled Always Search User Paths under Search Paths of Build Settings, and the project built.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a look if one of your source header files has the same name as a standard C++ or C header file. Quite possibly this prevents inclusion of the standard header file that defines struct tm. Look if there is a file "time.h" or "locale.h" or something like that has become part of your project.